# How to check if Image Data can be returned from a Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tiff

I am currently writing a Python module, in one portion of the function I am saving a tiff image to a dictionary. However I am not sure how to actually validate that this is happening? How do I call or return the array from the dictionary the tiff file is saved in? Do I simply need to end my function with return `optional_dict`?

```
optional_dict={}
if showMaps==True:#Conditional argument for saving the tiff image
    #Tiff image saved in a temporary directory
    with open(outputdir+f"ROI-{NAME}-thickness_tif", 'rb') as f:
        thickness_tif = f.read()# Read tiff image
    thickness_tif = optional_dict["thickness_tif"] #Save to dictionary with keyword
```

Comment: Your question and code don't make much sense. Please elaborate on what it is you want to do (and put it in the question, not down here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save `thickness_tif` to a dictionary `optional_dict`, you have to reverse the expression:

```
# Save to dictionary with keyword
# INCORRECT: thickness_tif = optional_dict["thickness_tif"]
optional_dict["thickness_tif"] = thickness_tif
```

And if you want to check what was written, you may simply `print` the value stored in your dictionary:

```
print(optional_dict["thickness_tif"])
```